# Moto G 2nd Gen - caught in a boot loop

Tags: boot-loop, motorola-moto-g

My Moto G 2nd Gen, got caught in a boot loop. My phone keeps restarting, but doesn't get past the screen where Motorolla symbol with 'powered by android'title at the bottom shows up. Is there a known solution for this problem ??

Comment: did U got any sol?

Comment: @PadmaKumar I did..I had to factory reset my mobile. Follow the link in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to factory reset my mobile. If you don't know how to do that, you can  refer  [this](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/97329/p/30,6720,9050) artice...